# Show that $\forall{a,b,n}\in\mathbb{N},\ gcd(a^n,b^n)=gcd(a,b)^n$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Need help proving the relation above, I'm assuming it can be done using gcd properties.

Answer (score 3):

Write $a=gx$ and $b=gy$ where $g=gcd(a,b)$. Then $x,y$ are relatively prime. So $a^n = g^nx^n$ and $b=g^ny^n$. Since $x^n$ and $y^n$ are relatively prime we have $$gcd(a^n,b^n) = g^n$$