# If GCD(a,b)=d then GCD(a^n,b^n)=d^n?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If GCD(a,b)=d,

> then can we say that GCD(a^n,b^n)=d^n? for all positive integers n.

This doubt is inspired from GCD(a,b)=1 implies GCD(a^n,b^n)=1 for all positive integers n.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/524454/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2681028/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2544681/42969

Comment: ... all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cgcd(a%5En%2C%20b%5En)%20%3D%20d%5En%24)